# Getting the handle of the currently focused control inside another application

Tags: user-interface, winapi, hook

How would one retrieve the handle of the control that currently has focus ? I am using WH_KEYBOARD_LL to capture all keypresses in, and I should be able to determine in which textbox the user is typing in. The code capturing the events has no direct access to the
controls in the other application.

I know the win32 function GetFocus() exists for getting the current window handle, but I need something similar for the current control.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Pika

Comment: I should add that when running in full .NET, the GetFocus function returns a unique Hwnd for each control I'm typing in. However, when typing in a Visual Foxpro application (which hosts this managed dll via COM), the Hwnd is only unique per window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the GUI thread ID to [`GetGUIThreadInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633506%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which will provide you with a `GUITHREADINFO.hwndFocus`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem remains the same as with GetFocus(). It seems I cannot get the handles of the controls inside Visual Foxpro. All I can get are the windows and child windows inside the application.

Comment: Have you spy++'d it? perhaps the controls are not windows but are drawn instead (like MS Forms)

Comment: I just did, but the depth is also limited to windows, toolbars, treeviews, imagelists, not deeper like you would see in a .NET Forms app. I found the following post (http://www.mofeel.net/110-microsoft-public-fox-programmer-exchange/10593.aspx): FoxPro does not use GDI to draw its controls, but it paints them like bitmaps. Seems like it's impossible what I'd like to do.

Comment: I'm gonna try to find another solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more general WH_MSGFILTER (it's called within context of the monitored thread so you must create a DLL). The callback gets MSG structure containing all informations about message (handle too).

Comment: I took a look at the API, the callback also returns a Hwnd, but in the case of Foxpro, there is none. I will have the same problem. Thanks anyway (I didn't know about that hook)