# How to uniquely identify a field or control in an application using Hooks?

Tags: c#, hook

Is there a way to uniquely identify a control/ field present in an active application (be it .exe application or web browser) using Hooks?
Like getting its id.
I have used Hooks to identify the active application, its window title, mouse and keyboard events. But couldn't find any hook to get the id of the control the cursor is on.

Comment: Maybe it is due to the lack of sleeping but: **Sir, I have no idea what you are talking about...** Can you show some code or whatever you have tried and specify your exact problem with that? Please also consider reading about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/586479 and from there also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint (window here also includes controls). It might be necessary to translate screen coordinates to client coordinates beforehand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333570/getting-the-handle-of-the-currently-focused-control-inside-another-application